# How to set value of row item in Table Layout dynamically in android?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

i am creating dynamic row and add this row in table layout .During time of       row creation ,value of each textView is set. But we get problem on setting the value on click listener of each row item.Actually we have two textView inside each row and onclick of first text view we open data picker . so i want to so date value at textview .

```
tableLayout = (TableLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_popup);
View tableRow =  LayoutInflater.from(MileStoneActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.cdd_popup1st_row, null, false);
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            for (int i = 0; i < masterDataList.size(); i++) {
               /* if (i == 0) {
                    View tableRow = LayoutInflater.from(MileStoneActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.cdd_popup1st_row, null, false);
                    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

                } else {*/
                final   View  tableRow1 =   LayoutInflater.from(MileStoneActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.cdd_popup_row, null, false);
                      tableRow1.setId(i);
                    tv1 = (TextView)tableRow1.findViewById(R.id.textView24);
                    tv2 = (TextView)tableRow1.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
                    tv2.setId(i);
                    tv1.setText(masterDataList.get(i).getLineItemNumber());
                    tv2.setText((masterDataList.get(i).getRequestedDeliveryDate()));

                tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        rowNumber = tableRow1.getId();


                        new DatePickerDialog(MileStoneActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

                        // dialog.dismiss();


                        //  }

                    }
                });

                    tableLayout.addView(tableRow1);
```

This is my date picker listner:
 myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

```
                final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                          int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateLabel();
                    }

                };
```

i failed to set text value of tv2. i want to change the value of particular row that has been clicked . Kindly help me . any help would be Appreciated in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I d'nt know if I got you right, but you could make date a method returning the listener. In the method pass the tv2 as parameter, and then updateLabel with this parameter.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener getDate(final TextView tv){
    return new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                          int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateLabel(tv);
                    }

                };
}
```

Then do this in DatePicker constructor:

```
new DatePickerDialog(MileStoneActivity.this, getDate(tv2), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Comment: Thx for your response. but how can i know which row tv2 textView belong to

Comment: @Anand Passing the tv you can get the parentView, that will be the row

Comment: it will set the value of last row textview, not desired row

Comment: Plz tell me any other way to set value .. i am not getting .. it took long time